# How to connect to mysql in pycharm community edition?

Tags: python, pycharm, mysql-connector-python

I have a fresh install of pycharm community edition 2019.2 on mac 10.13.1

I want to connect to the mysql database I have locally.

I wrote a python file that starts

`import mysql.connector`

The 'mysql' part is underlined red, so I hover over it and get the message 'no module named mysql - install package mysql'

I click on the link and it says 'packages installed successfully - installed packages : mysql'

But the 'mysql' part of 'mysql.connector' remains red and it still says I haven't installed mysql.

What am I missing? Would hope this would be more intuitive.

Thanks!

Comment: No joy restarting PyCharm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install [mysql-connector-python](https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/) (you can also install it from project interpreter).

Answer (score 1):

Install The mysql-connector

Here 2 way to install this module in the pycharm community edition.

1. pip install mysql-connector-python
2. Click file->Setting->Project:Your-Project->Python Interpreter-> + -> Search mysql-connector-python

After installing this module import in your script(Code)

- import mysql.connector
- connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', database='Your-DatabaseName', user='root', password='root')
- if connection.is_connected():
  print("Connection Successfully")